# PS/2 info search

Tags: bus, ps2

Could you please help me find information about PS/2 protocol?

I am currently writing a topic for an exam, it is about serial buses. What I need is to be able to create a suitable circuit to connect with exact bus type + write the timing diagram. However, I failed to find information about the main principles of its implementation, nor have I found the inner structure...

Wikipedia doesn't count. The German article is better than the English or the Czech one, but I don't have much time on translation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2-Schnittstelle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google "ps/2 keyboard protocol"

The first hit, http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2protocol/ is a good explanation (I used it a few years ago to write an interface), http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/The_PS2_protocol/ seems good too.

Comment: Dear Mr. Wouter van Ooijen, thank you very much indeed, the articles are great! I am really new to electrical engineering and it seems that I just used wrong search parameters. From now on, I will be looking for what you advised.

Comment: Sometimes a few good search terms is all one needs :)